# How to create PPTP VPN connection in ios Programmatically?

Tags: ios

I want to create a pptp Vpn connection programmatically in Ios 8. I followed this [link](http://ramezanpour.net/post/2014/08/03/configure-and-manage-vpn-connections-programmatically-in-ios-8/). By the help of this link i am able to create an IPSec Vpn connection in ios.

But i need to create a pptp vpn connection if any one know about it then please help me how to do it i am very stuck in it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no pptp api support in iOS (currently 9.3.4). The only supported protocols are

- IKEv1 (IPSec)
- IKEv2 (AES and certificates)

To use these, have a look at NEVPNManager and NEVPNProtocolIPSec class reference.
There's also a good example here:
http://ramezanpour.net/post/2014/08/03/configure-and-manage-vpn-connections-programmatically-in-ios-8/

If you really want to to have pptp, then you have to write your own extension, using the Network Extension framework and for that you need a special entitlement from apple, i.e. you have to write them an email and explain why you need this right.

Cheers